# D3.js: plot dots on the existing line in a multiseries line chart with long formatted data

Tags: d3.js

I have used the chart example as given here:
http://bl.ocks.org/natemiller/20f9bd99d1795e3a0b1c

However, when trying to plot the data points over the individual lines, it doesnt show up. The code is given here:

```
var cities = svg.selectAll(".city")
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "city");

cities.append("path")   //adding paths
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
  .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.key); });

cities.selectAll(".dot")   //adding dots
        .data(data, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class","dualLineChart-dot1")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.values); })
        .attr("r", 3.5)
        .on("mouseover", function(d){ 
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(){
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");
        });
```

the CSS part is as follows:

```
.line {
     fill: none;
     stroke-width: 1.5px;
 }

.dot {
     fill: white;
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

Comment: For `circle` element you need to change `.attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })` with `cx` and `cy` attributes.

Comment: I did try that as well. I used it in this way:
    `.attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })`
    `.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.values); }`
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a few changes to get this to work:

1. Make sure your class names are consistent: Change `cities.selectAll(".dot")` to `cities.selectAll(".dualLineChart-dot1")` to match with the class attr you assign a few lines later
2. The y-accessor is `d.temp`, rather than `d.values`, so you should have `.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temp); })` to get the y-value
3. Most importantly, you should change the way you get the data for the points. Because the `cities` variable already is an array of data (split up by city), you just need to access it for your points using `.data(function(d) { return d.values; })`, instead of using `.data(data, function(d) { return d.values; })`

Here's the working code:

```
cities.selectAll(".dualLineChart-dot1")   //adding dots
    .data(function(d) { return d.values; })
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class","dualLineChart-dot1")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.temp); })
    .attr("r", 3.5)
    .on("mouseover", function(d){ 
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");
    });
```

Comment: The class names were changed later, silly mistake from my part! Thankyou so much for your help! It worked!! :)